# Plot color based on value of y in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

Hi I would like to plot with different color based  value (eg < 0).  I found a solution on a previous post but when I tried to duplicate it failed.

```
plot(-10:10,
     type="o", 
     pch = 19,
     col = ifelse(x < 0,'red','green'),
     xaxt = "n",
)
```

I also tried this but did not work as well.

```
plot(-10:10,
     type="o", 
     pch = 19,
     col = if(x < 0){'red'} else{'green'},
     xaxt = "n",
)
```

When I do the above, all  I get is green; reversing from < to > makes everything red, so it treats all the value as > 0.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a "black" line and coloured dots in the comments, try:

```
x=-10:10
plot(x, type = "l"); points(x, pch = 19, col = ifelse(x < 0, 'red', 'green'))
```

[image]

Comment: clever; many thanks.  For some reason, depending what the values are, some numbers despite being > 0 still shows up red...its so bizarre

Comment: @Ahdee Could you provide example data ? Also, try `text(x, labels=x, pos = 1)` to label the points and see their values

Comment: Thanks Steven; I think it would be better to start  a new thread  in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The plot function does not know what x is in your example. This works:

```
x=-10:10
plot(x,pch=19,type="o",col=ifelse(x<0,'red','green'))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `x` before:

```
x <- -10:10
plot(x, type="o", pch = 19, col = ifelse(x < 0,'red','green'))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks; works great by any chance do you know how to change the line of the color to black?